# Texto saindo da tabela depois de acrescentar imagens

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma tabela composta por 5 linhas e 3 colunas em que a primeira e a terceira coluna estão sendo preenchidas por gifs, e a segunda coluna está sendo preenchida por texto. O meu problema é o seguinte: quando adiciono o atributo `rowspan` para os gifs ocuparem toda a coluna, o texto simplesmente sai para fora da tabela. Alguém sabe como resolver?

Código:

```html
<body>
    <table style="border: 1px solid #FF0000; background-color: #FF6347; color: white;"> 
        <tr style="border: 1px solid #FF0000;"> 
            <td rowspan="5" style="border: 1px solid #FF0000;"> <img src="Personagens/Benga/benga_sprites/benga_sprites_imagens/benga_gif.gif"></td>
            <td>NOME</td>
            <td rowspan="5" style="border: 1px solid #FF0000;"> <img src="Personagens/Benga/benga_pokemons/benga_pokemons_sprites/benga_charizard.gif"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border: 1px solid #FF0000;"> 
            <td> </td>
            <td>NOME</td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border: 1px solid #FF0000;">
            <td> </td>
            <td>NOME</td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border: 1px solid #FF0000;">
            <td> </td>
            <td>NOME</td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border: 1px solid #FF0000;">
            <td>  </td>
            <td>NOME</td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
```

Resultado:

[image: Captura de tela mostrando o problema]

Comment: Não tem nada _saindo pra fora_ da tabela aí.

Comment: Eu falo saindo como se as palavras fossem pra outro local sem ser o programado, pq pra mim elas deverias ficar no centro(coluna2), mas é como se tivessem ido pra uma 4° coluna que eu nem criei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo seu problema são essas `<td>` vazias. Se vc usou `rowspan` vc não precisa deixar vazio, vc tem que simplesmente remove-las

```html
    <table style="border: 1px solid #FF0000; background-color: #FF6347; color: white;"> 
        <tr style="border: 1px solid #FF0000;"> 
            <td rowspan="5" style="border: 1px solid #FF0000;"> <img src="Personagens/Benga/benga_sprites/benga_sprites_imagens/benga_gif.gif"></td>
            <td>NOME</td>
            <td rowspan="5" style="border: 1px solid #FF0000;"> <img src="Personagens/Benga/benga_pokemons/benga_pokemons_sprites/benga_charizard.gif"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border: 1px solid #FF0000;"> 
            
            <td>NOME</td>
            
        </tr>

        <tr style="border: 1px solid #FF0000;">
            
            <td>NOME</td>
            
        </tr>

        <tr style="border: 1px solid #FF0000;">
            
            <td>NOME</td>
            
        </tr>

        <tr style="border: 1px solid #FF0000;">
           
            <td>NOME</td>
            
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: Ata, achei que só era possível usar o rowspan caso tivesse as colunas pra ocupar

Comment: @LucasSouza tanto rowspan quanto colspan é para vc justamente não precisar colocar TDs vazias, pois mesmo uma TD vazia ocupa espaço, uma célula vazia ainda é uma célula.